# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setProject.bind') onPress

Tags: react-native

React native beginner here, I'm trying to make an app that runs a function when I press on my custom made component but when I try do to so, I get the "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.setProject.bind')" error...

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props){

super(props);

projets = [
    {
        "text":"ProjectName",
        "progress":"30",
        "budget":"36000",
        "totalDays":"50",
        "design":"10",
        "integration":"12",
        "dev":"30"
    },

var progress = 0;
var totalDays = 54;
var budget = 24000;

this.state = {
  projets: projets,
  progress: progress,
  totalDays: totalDays,
  budget: budget
}

this.setProject = this.setProject.bind(this);

}
```

....

```
  setProject() {
    console.log("test");
  }

  render() {

var projectsArray = [];

return (
```

.....

```
    <ScrollView style={{flex: 3, flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'}}>

      {this.state.projets.forEach(function(projet, index) {

        projectsArray.push(
            <ItemProjet onPress={() => {this.setProject.bind(this)}} selected={false} key={index} progress={projet.progress} budget={projet.budget} totalDays={parseInt(projet.design)+parseInt(projet.integration)+parseInt(projet.dev)} text={projet.text} design={projet.design} integration={projet.integration} dev={projet.dev}/>
        );

      })}

      {projectsArray}

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

**First:** - You don't need to bind your function in 3 ways which makes the code redundant.
Therefore you can just call `onPress={this.setProject}`

**Second:** - Rather than using `forEach`, *pushing the array* and then rendering it, you can simply use the `map` function which *creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.*

Therefore you can do

```
   {this.state.projets.map((projet, index) => ( //... Use arrow function here to bind this parameter

     <ItemProjet key={index} onPress={this.setProject} selected={false}
       key={index} progress={projet.progress} budget={projet.budget}
       totalDays={parseInt(projet.design)+parseInt(projet.integration)+parseInt(projet.dev)}
       text={projet.text} design={projet.design} integration={projet.integration} dev={projet.dev}/>
    ))}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, spent a day trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function like this (auto bind to your class):

```
setProject = () => {
  console.log("test");
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
<ItemProjet onPress={this.setProject} //other props />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to solve this particular use case.

In your case, you can declare the `setProject()` function in the following way within your component:

```
    setProject = () => {
      console.log('test');
    };
```

After this, you can invoke the function by simply typing:

`this.setProject()` or `onClick={this.setProject}`